# Declaring a 2D vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

In some cases only the below line works.Why so?

```
vector< vector<int>> a(M,N);
```

This works in every case.

```
vector< vector<int>> a(M, vector<int> (N));
```

What's the difference?

Comment: Your first method of declaring a vector will not create a 2D vector. It will create a vector of size M with default values N.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`std::vector` has a fill constructor which creates a vector of n elements and fills with the value specified. `a` has the type `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` which means that it is a vector of a vector. Hence your default value to fill the vector is a vector itself, not an `int`. Therefore the second options is the correct one.

`std::vector<std::vector<int>> array_2d(rows, std::vector<int>(cols, 0));`

This creates a rows * cols 2D array where each element is 0. The default value is `std::vector<int>(cols, 0)` which means each row has a vector which has `cols` number of element, each being 0.

Comment: Both give the same thing and I tried debugging. Why not the first one which tells to create a vector of vectors through vector( vector<int> > but why the last vector<int> as in vector( vector<int>) a(m, **vector<int> (n)**)
@Akash Pradhan

Comment: Your first one will produce error and not compile. Here is an example of the error. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c2ef8dc8777df00e

Answer (score 2):

For declaring a 2D vector we have to first define a 1D array of size equal to number of rows of the desired 2D vector.
Let we want to create a vector of k rows and m columns

```
 "vector<vector<int>> track(k);"
```

This will create a vector of size k. Then use resize method.

```
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    track[i].resize(m);
```

In this way you can declare a 2D vector