# How to make a two dimensional array with user input variables?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, multidimensional-array, user-input

I was working in a project, and everything was running smoothly up to this point

```
int Get_floors()
{
   cout << "Enter how many floors does the stablishment have" << endl;
   int floors;   
   cin >> floors;

   cout << "Enter how many places does each floor have" << endl;
   int places;
   cin >> places;

   constexpr int floorsc = floors;
   constexpr int placesc = places;

   bool lugs[floorsc][placesc];
}
```

I was trying to make a two dimensional with user-set columns and rows, but it asks for the variable `floors` and `places` to be constant.

Comment: [VLAs are not part of standard C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard), you want a [2D-vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663299/declaring-a-2d-vector/53249071)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Declaring a 2D vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663299/declaring-a-2d-vector)

Comment: Use dynamic memory allocation concept for 2D array!

Comment: For a problem like this, I'd use [something like this simple matrix class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/4581301)

Answer (score 3):

Array sizes need to be compile-time constants, but yours are not. So this:

```
 bool lugs[floorsc][placesc];
```

is really a **variable-length array**, which is *[not part of the standard C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/)*. Writing the user inputs to be `constexpr` will not evaluate them to compile time.

Since the user inputs are only known at run time, you need something which will be created at run time and (memory, growth, etc) managements happen also at run time.

The perfect candidate for this from the standard library is [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

In short, you could have the following:

```
#include <vector>  // std::vector

int Get_floors()
{
   std::cout << "Enter how many floors does the stablishment have" << std::endl;
   int floors; std::cin >> floors;

   std::cout << "Enter how many places does each floor have" << std::endl;
   int places;    std::cin >> places;

   // vector of vector bools
   std::vector<std::vector<bool>> lugs(floors, std::vector<bool>(places));

   return {}; // appropriate return;
}
```

---

When you have understood about `std::vector` and the draw backs of having `std::vector` of `std::vector`s, you could try to provide a class, which acts like a 2d array but internally just uses `std::vector<Type>`. Here is an [example which might be helpful in that case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076624/c-matrix-class/2076668#2076668) (*Credits [@user4581301](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4581301/user4581301)*).

Also, you might be interesting to have a read on the following:

[Why isn't vector<bool> a STL container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794569/)

---

As a side note, *[do not practice with `using namespce std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/)*

Comment: Quick caveat: `std::vector<bool>` can be implemented to pack the bools into bits to save space. As a result `vector<bool>` is a bit different from regular `vector`s and [gets its own documentation page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) to cover the differences. Sometimes it's better to make a `vector` out of a `char` or other small integer instead.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using a 2d array, you can easily use a 2d `vector`. it will be pretty easy to work if you have to define your arrays based on dynamic variables like user inputs.